# Primeng column-filter fails because of empty datatable filters object

Tags: angular, filter, primeng

I`ve run into tricky bug with primeng table filters (version 11). May be someone met it before?

I have usual primeng table with LazyLoad event. I`ve got huge amount of filters in that table. Some of them are new p-columnFilter with ability to choose filter-rule (contains/starts, etc)

Several days ago one of the user said that choose-how-to-filter filter doesn`t work. It shows him empty list of options and do not trigger table filtering. But sometimes it works correctly.

I cannot reproduce this bug on my PC. Actually, that user is the only one who see that bug from time to time.

I found that table got empty filters on init and it crushes everything. Those filters have interesting function in template. It checks which option is chosen.

```
[ngClass]="{'p-highlight': isRowMatchModeSelected(matchMode.value)}"
```

and it doesn`t check if table has empty filters object (on init):

```
isRowMatchModeSelected(matchMode: string) {
    return (<FilterMetadata> this.dt.filters[this.field]).matchMode === matchMode;
}
```

So in my case this no-checking-if-it-empty-filters ruin everything. Do anybody have any idea what can cause this situation or how to fix it?